# Removing the "word" from whole data or ignore it

Tags: r

I edited my data and it looks like below:

```
           Sequence       modifications                      No_Ks No_Ks_modif diff
1   AAAAGAAAVANQGKK       Acetyl Acetyl                        2           2    0
2 AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE       Acetyl Biotin Acetyl                 3           3    0
3 AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE       Acetyl Acetyl                        3           2    1
4 IKKVGYNPKTVPFVPIS       Acetyl Acetyl Acetyl Oxidation       3           4   -1
```

No_Ks -> total number of K in the sequence
No_Ks_modif -> number of modified K by acetyl or biotin (should be only) but it counts a Oxidation aswell so that's why the number of K's modified if higher and a total number of them.

I used the code below to count the number of modified K (from the sequence):

```
# Count of modifications    
dataset[, No_Ks_modif := 6]
dataset[V6 == "", No_Ks_modif := 5]
dataset[V5 == "", No_Ks_modif := 4]
dataset[V4 == "", No_Ks_modif := 3]
dataset[V3 == "", No_Ks_modif := 2]
dataset[V2 == "", No_Ks_modif := 1]
dataset[V1 == "", No_Ks_modif := 0]

# Retaining Acetyl/Biotin or no modification only
dataset[, AB01 := TRUE]
dataset[, AB02 := TRUE]
dataset[, AB03 := TRUE]
dataset[, AB04 := TRUE]
dataset[, AB05 := TRUE]
dataset[, AB06 := TRUE]

dataset[V1 != "",  AB01 := grepl(V1, pattern = "Acetyl|Biotin|Oxidation")]
dataset[V2 != "",  AB02 := grepl(V2, pattern = "Acetyl|Biotin|Oxidation")]
dataset[V3 != "",  AB03 := grepl(V3, pattern = "Acetyl|Biotin|Oxidation")]
dataset[V4 != "",  AB04 := grepl(V1, pattern = "Acetyl|Biotin|Oxidation")]
dataset[V5 != "",  AB05 := grepl(V2, pattern = "Acetyl|Biotin|Oxidation")]
dataset[V6 != "",  AB06 := grepl(V3, pattern = "Acetyl|Biotin|Oxidation")]


dataset <- dataset[AB01 & AB02 & AB03 & AB04 & AB05 & AB06]
```

If I remove the "Oxidation" from the code it won't count whole row and that's the problem.

I see two ways to do it. One way might be to only count Biotin and Acetyl as a modification, my script can't do it. Second way is to remove the "Oxidation" from all of the columns, neither don't know how to do that. Any suggestions are welcome.

Stupid question in the end. Is there any way to paste huge code in proper way without pressing 4 times space in all lines of the code?

Edit:
Dataset before running whole code involved only 2 columns:

```
Sequence                 modifications
AAAAGAAAVANQGKK     [14] Acetyl (K)|[15] Acetyl (K)
AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE   [4] Acetyl (K)|[7] Acetyl (K)
```

And much more rows.

Comment: What does `dataset` look like before you run all of that code?

Comment: Already edited first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certainly easier ways to do this.  Here is one example.  First I'll reconstruct your dataset the way I think it is:

```
> df=read.table(text="Sequence                 modifications
+ AAAAGAAAVANQGKK     '[14] Acetyl (K)|[15] Acetyl (K)'
+ AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE   '[4] Acetyl (K)|[7] Acetyl (K)'",h=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
> dt<-data.table(df)
> dt
            Sequence                   modifications
1:   AAAAGAAAVANQGKK [14] Acetyl (K)|[15] Acetyl (K)
2: AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE   [4] Acetyl (K)|[7] Acetyl (K)
```

Now you can use `strsplit` to do your work:

```
dt[,no_Ks:=lapply(strsplit(Sequence,""),function(x) sum(x=="K"))]
dt[,no_Ks_modif:=lapply(strsplit(modifications," "),
        function(x) sum(x %in% c("Acetyl","Biotin")))]
dt
##             Sequence                   modifications no_Ks no_Ks_modif
## 1:   AAAAGAAAVANQGKK [14] Acetyl (K)|[15] Acetyl (K)     2           2
## 2: AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE   [4] Acetyl (K)|[7] Acetyl (K)     3           2
```

Comment: I think the no_Ks should count for occurrence of "(K)" instead of just "K". The OP should have mentioned it in the question though.

Comment: A small error appeared. Could you help me with that: Error in strsplit(Sequence, "") : non-character argument. dataset is made by data.table function. Do you think it might be a reason ?

Comment: Make sure that Sequence is of class character and not a factor: `class(dt$Sequence)` should return `character`.

Comment: You were right, changed it using "dataset$Sequence <- as.character(dataset$Sequence)". Another problem appeared in second line of code: Error in +function(x) sum(x %in% c("Acetyl", "Biotin")) : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: What is `class(dt$modifications)` and `dt$modifications[1]`?

Comment: both factor. Should I change to character aswell ? Already tried to change it and it didn't help. Same problem.

Comment: Yes, if you want to manipulate them as strings, you need to convert to character.  This is something to keep in mind generally, as it comes up frequently.

Comment: Did it and it didn't help. Sorry for my stupidity. I started to lear R like week ago and trying to do fast progress just by asking people around how to do something.

Comment: Oh, the problem is that the "+" character is not part of the actual code.  That just came from my R session because of multiple lines.  See the edit.

Comment: ... that was stupid from my side aswell. Thanks for the patience.